# How to revert all migrations at once in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake, database-migration

I tried to run:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

It reverts all migrations **except the last one**.

Then I tried to run:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<timestamp_of_last_migration>
```

but it didn't revert either. Why ?

Is there a command that runs all `down` methods at once ?

Comment: Searching on how to rollback all migrations, I stumbled onto this question. I just want to say that nowadays (Rails 3.2.9) `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` seems to be working fine, reverting all migrations.

Comment: This question seems to be wrong or out-of-date. `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` rollbacks every migration, **including the first one**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your database only related to this project, and you are trying to undo everything in your migrations, I'd simply drop the database, and then run rake db:create.

Then you have an empty database ready to go.

Or is there another reason you're trying to run the down scripts?

Comment: That's what I did finally. But, I still wonder why the commands above didn't work...

Comment: Trolled through the rails rake tasks, and it looks like rake db:drop db:create is the only real option. I'd say the reason migrations won't let you go back to nothing, is because they were intended for moving around INSIDE the migrations. Not reseting back to zero.

Answer (score 10):

You could check this list.

Maybe this could help you

```
rake db:create[:all]: If :all not specified then create the database defined in config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV. If :all is specified then create all of the databases defined in config/database.yml.
rake db:fixtures:load: Load fixtures into the current environment's database. Load specific fixtures using FIXTURES=x,y
rake db:migrate [VERSION=n]: Migrate the database through scripts in db/migrate. Target specific version with VERSION=n
rake db:migrate:redo [STEP=n]: (2.0.2) Revert the database by rolling back "STEP" number of VERSIONS and re-applying migrations.
rake db:migrate:reset: (2.0.2) Drop the database, create it and then re-apply all migrations. The considerations outlined in the note to rake db:create apply.
rake db:reset: Drop and re-create database using db/schema.rb. The considerations outlined in the note to rake db:create apply.
rake db:rollback [STEP=N]: (2.0.2) Revert migration 1 or n STEPs back.
rake db:schema:dump: Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load: Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:sessions:clear: Clear the sessions table
rake db:sessions:create: Creates a sessions table for use with CGI::Session::ActiveRecordStore
rake db:structure:dump: Dump the database structure to a SQL file
rake db:test:clone: Recreate the test database from the current environment's database schema
rake db:test:clone_structure: Recreate the test databases from the development structure
rake db:test:prepare: Prepare the test database and load the schema
rake db:test:purge: Empty the test database
```

Answer (score 7):

there is another way:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=100
```

this will revert last 100 migrations

taken from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<timestamp_of_first_migration>
```

this will run the self.down for your first migration, essentially wiping everything out.  at least, it just did for me!